# Change Comment date from "friendly" to useful format

Tags: tfs, azure-devops

In Visual Studio Team Services, comments have a date like "*commented 3 weeks ago*", which I believe is called a "friendly date". I can hover over the string, wait for a few moments, then a more informative value appears like "Friday, December 16, 2016 4:24:53 PM".

When using a different application and reading dates from TFS, I must refocus on TFS, hover over the friendly date, wait for the display, remember the values, refocus on the other application, then type in the value (hopefully correctly).

This is time consuming and error prone, how can I get TFS to display the actual date and time rather than the "friendly" value?

Also, how can I format the string to be consistent with how dates and times are shown elsewhere like "2016-12-16 16:24:53"?

Answer (score 1):

TL;DR; you can't, there is no way to customize the format.

Why are you manually porting comment dates to anothe platform. TFS has a very rich API and you could easily create a PowerShell script to pull the real date for you.

Comment: For example, when writing a report about a particular defect. I don't think I should need to start writing code to use a tool that should let me configure the date format as a user setting. Also, many people who use TFS are not programmers. But thanks for clearing that up. ;-)